# How to initialize array in Pascal using type?

Tags: arrays, pascal, freepascal

For the sake of fun, I'd like to refresh my Pascal knowledge, so gotta review the basics again.

Let's see this Java code:

```
class ArrayTest {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        int[] numArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    }
}
```

Rewrite that into Pascal:

```
type
    arrNum = array[1..10] of integer;
var
    BBB: arrNum;

begin
    BBB := [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,10];
end.
```

Compiling the code with FPC 3.2.2 on MacOS, the result is:

> arrnum.pas(7,12) Error: Incompatible types: got "{Array Of Const/Constant Open} Array > of ShortInt" expected "arrNum"
>
> arrnum.pas(10) Fatal: There were 1 errors compiling module, stopping
>
> Fatal: Compilation aborted Error: /usr/local/bin/ppcx64 returned an
> error exitcode

What's wrong here?

Comment: Try declaring `arrNum` as `TArray<Integer>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

A similar syntax using a constructor is available for dynamic arrays (BBB), but not for static ones. Static initializations can be done by assigning a type constant to a variable (BB10:=CCC10) or by defining an initialized constant(DDD10).

The below code demonstrates some cases:

```
{$mode delphi} 
type
    arrNum = array of integer;
    arrNum10 = array[0..9] of integer;

const CCC10 : arrNum10 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
var
    BBB: arrNum;
    BBB10 : arrNum10;


    DDD10  : arrnum10 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

begin
    BBB := ArrNum.Create(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,10);
    BBB10:=CCC10;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you declare as an array you should use a for loop to init

```
type
    arrNum = array [ 1..10] of integer;
var
    BBB: arrNum;
    i: integer;

begin
    for i:=1 to 10 do
    BBB[i] := i;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it in the declaration:

```
program ideone;
type
    arrNum = array[1..10] of integer;
var
    BBB: arrNum = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,10);
    i: Integer;
begin
    for i := 1 to 10 do
        Write(BBB[i])
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

In Pascal `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 10]` is a `set` literal containing 9 distinct `integer` values.
You cannot assign sets to an `array` data type variable.

Instead you will need to specify an `array` literal and properly denote it, like so:

```pascal
arrNum[1: 1; 2: 2; 3: 3; 4: 4; 5: 5; 6: 6; 7: 7; 8: 8; 9: 8; 10: 10]
```

---

However, as of version 3.2.0 the FPC does not (yet) comply with the Extended Pascal specification (ISO standard 10206).
They brewed up their own Pascal, so the compiler (“mis‑”)identifies your `set` literal as an “{Array Of Const/Constant Open} Array of ShortInt”.
See [Marco’s answer](/a/71831788) how to initialize “[dynamic arrays](https://wiki.FreePascal.org/Dynamic_array)” as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it using for loop

> for i := 1 to 10 do
> BBB[i]:=i;

or

> for i := 1 to 10 do
> BBB[i]:=0;

Answer (score 0):

Using a dynamic array and delphi compatibility mode, it is possible to assign an array using this syntax:

```
{$mode delphi}

type
  arrNum = TArray<integer>;
var
  BBB: arrNum;    
begin
  BBB := [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,10];
end.
```

If you want a static constant (dynamic) array, the assignment is similar:

```
const
  BBB : arrNum = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,10];
```