# Is there a way to initialize all items in a 2D array in Pascal on one line (without looping)?

Tags: arrays, pascal

I know that instead of doing the following for a 1D array of Integer, arr,

```
SetLength(arr, 4);
arr[0] := 11;
arr[1] := 12;
arr[2] := 13;
arr[3] := 13;`
```

I can also do the above just on one line:

```
arr := [11, 12, 13, 14];
```

Now for a 2D array of array of Integer example (with dimensions 2, 2),

```
arr[0][0] := 11;
arr[0][1] := 12;
arr[1][0] := 13;
arr[1][1] := 14;
```

**Question**:
Can I also do this on one line *something like* the following?

```
arr := [[11, 12], [13, 14]];
```

**Notes**:

- I'm not interested in custom-written functions to "make life easier".  I'm strictly asking about default Pascal syntax.
- I already know how to work with (initialize) 2D arrays in Pascal via looping.  If that's the only way, I don't want to waste your time.  Just say that's the case.

Because this is a required field, again, I tried
`arr := [[11, 12], [13, 14]];`
but it didn't compile.  (Got a Type mismatch error.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize array in Pascal using type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71830962/how-to-initialize-array-in-pascal-using-type)

Comment: Not that I can see. What I deduced from your post there (which was about 1D arrays) and here is that the answer to my question is simply no... Unless I have imported “ISO standard 10206 Extended Pascal“. But my coding project is a scripting project for a game that has limited Pascal support, and none of the suggestions that you mentioned worked. To be fair, what you answered probably works for others, but I will wait for other answers too.

Comment: You do not “import” Extended Pascal. Either your processor supports it or it doesn’t. As far as I know there are _several_ extensions permitting to abbreviate things, but you were asking about `strictly […] default Pascal syntax.` If you have read carefully, my answer also provides an example for a multi‑dimensional array.

Comment: Oops.  Sorry.  It doesn't "support" it.  Again, thanks, but I cannot use Type in the scripting language I'm using except of it is followed by = record.  (So that would make each inner 1D array a property (rather than a dimension), and I would be forced to fill in the array with multiple lines of code anyway.)

Comment: What do you mean with *but I cannot use Type in the scripting language I'm using*? What is this scripting language? Why did you not mention it originally in your question?

Comment: I said I can use Type, as long as it's Type = record.  Also, I'm not an expert of Pascal to foresee that someone was going to use Type to cleverly solve this problem.  If I was, I wouldn't be asking a question on here.  (And using type to solve this problem seems redundant to me personally.  I would have never guessed.)  I tried my best to save people time in my post the best I could.  Lastly, knowing the scripting language is irrelevant if the only solution is the one given so far.  If there are alternative solutions, feel free to list them and I will try them out.

Answer (score 1):

ISO standard 10206 “Extended Pascal” defines the construct of an initial‑value specifier.

```pascal
var
    f: array[0..3] of integer value [0: 11; 1: 12; 2, 3: 13];
```

You can also assign `array` literals to a variable.
Structured value constructors must be prefixed with a data type:

```pascal
type
    t = array[0..1, 0..1] of integer;
var
    f: t;
begin
    f := t[0: [0: 1; 1: 2]; 1: [0: 3; 1: 4]];
```

The syntax also provides an `otherwise` clause for all members not explicitly defined.

```pascal
var
    f: array[0..9] of real value [5: 12.34; otherwise 56.78];
```

---

**Special case**:
If you want to initialize a one‑dimensional `array` of values in the range `0` through `ord(maxChar)` in one go, you could specify an adequate string literal.
You will then need to apply `ord` when reading `array` members.

```pascal
var
    s: string(8);
begin
    { Beware: The string is silently clipped. }
    s := chr(4) + chr(7) + chr(1) + chr(0) + chr(13) + chr(14) + chr(9) + chr(9)
```

Obviously this is really “hacky” in nature and not advisable for serious programming.
Keep in mind `maxChar` is an *implementation*‑defined constant, so not the same value everywhere.